# Unexpected token: punc (.) | npm run build failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, build

When I run "npm run build", i get the error unexpeceted token (.) what is on a ?. select for object values.

I have a tsc build for a react npm libary.

I think there is any config problem, so it can not read ?. I hope someone can help me with that.

This is the full error:

```
npm run build

> portshare-frontend-libary-components@0.1.0 build
> tsdx build

@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.
@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.
✓ Creating entry file 1.3 secs
⠦ Building modules
  902 |     header: /*#__PURE__*/React__default.createElement("div", {
  903 |       className: `contact-header ${type === exports.CardType.ADD ? 'addCard' : ''}`
> 904 |     }, /*#__PURE__*/React__default.createElement("h2", null, type === exports.CardType.ADD ? 'Add Contact' : contactCard?.element?.name), type !== exports.CardType.ADD && /*#__PURE__*/React__default.createElement(OptionButtonWithDropdown, {
      |                                                                                                                         ^ Unexpected token: punc (.)
  905 |       options: [{
  906 |         label: 'remove',
(terser plugin) SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)
    at ne (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:19592)
    at c (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:28298)
    at l (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:28389)
    at f (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:28442)
    at U (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:42256)
    at me (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:48326)
    at D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:49206
    at ve (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:49221)
    at ke (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:50475)
    at We (D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\node_modules\tsdx\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:50707)

PS D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components>
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  // see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig to better understand tsconfigs
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    // output .d.ts declaration files for consumers
    "declaration": true,
    // output .js.map sourcemap files for consumers
    "sourceMap": true,
    // match output dir to input dir. e.g. dist/index instead of dist/src/index
    "rootDir": "./src",
    // stricter type-checking for stronger correctness. Recommended by TS
    "strict": true,
    // linter checks for common issues
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // noUnused* overlap with @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars, can disable if duplicative
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    // use Node's module resolution algorithm, instead of the legacy TS one
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // transpile JSX to React.createElement
    "jsx": "react",
    // interop between ESM and CJS modules. Recommended by TS
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // significant perf increase by skipping checking .d.ts files, particularly those in node_modules. Recommended by TS
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // error out if import and file system have a casing mismatch. Recommended by TS
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // `tsdx build` ignores this option, but it is commonly used when type-checking separately with `tsc`
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // Enable importing JSON files
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Enable synthetic default imports
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true, // Allow accessing UMD globals
    "types": ["node"], // Include the 'node' type definitions
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"]
    },
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

This is my .babelrc.json:

```
{
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 100
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

and this is my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "name": "portshare-frontend-libary-components",
  "author": "Leon Salenbacher",
  "module": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.5",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "portshare-frontend-libary-objects": "^1.0.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "size-limit": "^8.2.4",
    "storybook": "^7.0.21",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

i changed
"target": "es5"  to "target": "es2020"
in tsconfig.json

and i updated my .babelrc.json to:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 100
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
  ]
}
```